# Unity3D movement way (Translate, MovePosition, velocity=, AddForce)

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm confused about movement in Unity3D. 
Let me clarify my understanding.

I think that movement depends on

- methods(Translate, MovePosition, velocity=, AddForce)
- Rigidbody.isKinematic

And the relationship can summarize below tabulated list.

[image: movement way table]

## information source

information source is docs.unity3d.com and [my experiment script](https://gist.github.com/onionmk2/c8285643a18a80f552a5c2fb5b9e8e31)

[doc](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.MovePosition.html) says that MovePosition cause a smooth transition When isKinematic == true, however, I can't reproduce it.

## Question.

is this table correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set `Interpolate` dropdown list to `Interpolate` on the rigibody then it will smooth out the transition using `MovePosition` when `isKinimatic`. Note: It will still move very fast, it will move there in 1 `FixedUpdate` but if you `step update` you will see that it tries to smooth the transition.

Comment: Thanks you for your answer. Perhaps what do you mean by `step update` is like this. https://gist.github.com/onionmk2/278d09b1f0beb7199ec42a7d6b4c4298 I can't figure out `smooth the transition` yet. But it seems to me your answer suggests that my tabulated list is substantially correct. Thanks :)